# JS condition on argument/variable's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something very simple on a progress-bar script but my non-existent knowledges of javascript are making me struggle a little bit.

What I have looks like this :

```
if (progress == 100) {
    var element = document.getElementById("avatar-progress");
    element.classList.add("finish");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#avatar-progress').circleProgress(
            'value',
            0
        );
    }, 250);
                }

if ($('#avatar-progress').circleProgress('value') == 0) {
    var element = document.getElementById("avatar-progress");
    element.removeAttribute("class");
}



$('#avatar-progress').circleProgress({
    value: 0,
    size: 156,
    fill: { color: "#60bcff" },
    emptyFill: "#ffffff",
    thickness: 2,
});
```

Basically what happens with this progress-bar is this :

when the uploading hits 100% : a class is added to #avatar-progress for a cool pulse effect, then, after the requiered delay for the pulse animation, the value is set back to 0, making the progress-bar disapear, and is ready for the next upload.

However, for the script's sake, I have to wait the value has returned to 0 before deleting the class (if I don't the pulse animation won't load again).

And this is what I failed to do, I don't know how to write it, as you see in my code I tried some stuffs :

```
if ($('#avatar-progress').circleProgress('value') == 0) {
    var element = document.getElementById("avatar-progress");
    element.removeAttribute("class");
}
```

but my condition doesn't work. I'm looking for some help to write this line the right way. Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do both things inside your `setTimeout` function:

```
if (progress === 100) {
  var element = document.getElementById('avatar-progress');
  element.classList.add('finish');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#avatar-progress').circleProgress('value', 0);
    element.classList.remove('finish');
  }, 250);
}
```

N.B. don't forget to use triple equals (`===`) in JavaScript, to ensure your comparison is correct.